# how to create datatable object for all sharepointlist that contain rows and columns

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create datatable object for all sharepoint list.
For Single list we can use the below link.
http://deepaksemwalsp.blogspot.in/2012/08/binding-data-from-sharepoint-list-to.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**I am not sure if you really want to do this, because it is very expensive performance wise.**

The answer is iterating over all Lists of the web object and using the code in the link, so something like this:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
DataSet set = new DataSet("All Tables Dataset");
foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
{
  SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt = bindToDataTable(items);
  set.Tables.Add(dt);
}
```

Bear in mind that you are now dealing with a Dataset with contains tables for all Lists. So you wont be able to bind them to a datagrid like in the article.

If you want to merge all lists into one table then you will need to modify the bindToDatabase method to append rows to your Table instead of creating a new Table everytime. And this assuming all your list have in common all the columns you need.